# Does changing the owner in a Firebase project change its google-service.json?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics

Tell me please. After adding new owner to **firebase** project which transfers project to new account. we need to add new project **google-service.json** file or can we use old one?

Comment: your question is not very clear, please read the details in this link on how to Ask Question on stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to add new google-service.json file.

Answer (score 2):

The collaborators on a Firebase project do not affect the contents of the `google-services.json` file. There is no need to redownload the `google-services.json` file after adding/changing collaborators or owners.